# HERE 3D Venue Navigation

Tags: navigation

I tried to implement Venue Navigation but I couldn't get the event listener to capture events when current maneuver is updated.

Here's what I did:

Here's what I implemented:

1.An interface for NavigationListener with the protocol functions

```
class NavigationListener: NSObject,NMAVenue3dNavigationListener{
    func navigationManagerDidReachDestination(_ navigationManager: NMAVenue3dNavigationManager) {
        print("reach destination")
func navigationManager(_ navigationManager: NMAVenue3dNavigationManager, hasCurrentManeuver maneuver: NMAVenue3dRouteManeuver?, nextManeuver: NMAVenue3dRouteManeuver?) {
        print("New Maneuver")      
    }
}
```

2. Adding the listener to the venue navigation manager

   ```
   self.venueMapLayer.venueNavigationManager.add(listener: NavigationListener())
   ```
3. Create the simulated position source and start the navigation manager

   let source = NMAVenue3dSimulatedPositionSource(routeSection: section!, speed: 20, distortionEnabled: false)
                   source.updatesInterval = 0.1
                   NMAPositioningManager.sharedInstance().dataSource = source
        self.venueMapLayer.venueNavigationManager.start(routeSection: section!, inCombinedRoute: combinedRoute)

Comment: Please provide the sdk version, mobile version you are using inorder to help you better.

Comment: Can you please provide your code on how you setup the NMAVenue3dMapLayer object and position indicator? That would help us to find the root cause.